# Jump if equal not ever jumping

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, x86-16, qemu

I'm writing nasm 16 bit code for a simple pong game, but even when my je is equal, it doesn't jump.

so far, it's meant to draw and top, bottom and middle line, and on the edges, it either draws 2 hashtags, to indicate whether pos1 or pos2 are there (player positions), but even when it is equal, it doesn't seem to print it.

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04

Here's the code (this is my first proper project, so it won't be very good):

```
[BITS 16]

start:
    call clearscreen

    mov ax, 07C0h       ; Set up 4K stack space after this bootloader
    add ax, 288     ; (4096 + 512) / 16 bytes per paragraph
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 4096

    mov ax, 07C0h       ; Set data segment to where we're loaded
    mov ds, ax

    mov si, topline ; Put string position into SI
    call print_string   ; Call our string-printing routine

    push si

    mov ECX, 23
    l3:
    push ECX

        push EDX
        mov EDX, pos1
        call checkdraw
        pop EDX

        mov ECX, 37
        l1:
            mov si, placeholder
            call print_string
        loop l1

        mov si, middleline
        call print_string

        mov ECX, 37
        l2:
            mov si, placeholder
            call print_string
        loop l2

        push EDX
        mov EDX, pos2
        call checkdraw
        pop EDX

    pop ECX
    dec ECX
    jnz l3

    pop si

    mov si, bottomline  ; Put string position into SI
    call print_string   ; Call our string-printing routine

    MOV     CX, 0fh
    MOV     DX, 4240h
    MOV     AH, 86h
    INT     15h

    jmp start           ; Jump here - infinite loop!

.data:

    pos1 dw 12
    pos2 dw 12

    player db '##', 0
    middleline db '||', 0
    placeholder db ' ', 0
    doubleplaceholder db '  ', 0
    topline db '================================================================================', 0
    bottomline db '===============================================================================', 0

clearscreen:
    pusha
    mov ah, 0x00
    mov al, 0x03
    int 10h
    popa

    ret

checkdraw:              ;doesn't work as intended

    cmp EDX, 12
    je drawplayer       ;jump if equal seems to never jump
    cmp ECX, EDX
    jne drawblank

drawplayer:
    push si
    mov si, player
    call print_string
    pop si
    ret

drawblank:
    push si
    mov si, doubleplaceholder
    call print_string
    pop si
    ret

print_string:
    mov ah, 0eh

.render:
    lodsb
    cmp al, 0
    je .done
    int 10h
    jmp .render

.done:
    ret

    times 510-($-$$) db 0   ; Pad remainder of boot sector with 0s
    dw 0xAA55       ; The standard PC boot signature
```

here's the compiling and running options:

```
nasm boot.asm -f bin -o boot.bin
dd status=noxfer conv=notrunc if=boot.bin of=boot.img
qemu-system-i386 -fda  boot.img
```

it probably doesn't change anything, but this is the python script I use to make running it easier:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

#helpStr = "-----Help-----\nThis section will contain all possible arguments, and their uses\n\n-----\n-l\n    'leave': don't delete the files included in the process of compliling\n\n-----\n-h\n    'help': shows a help message"

import os
import sys

args = sys.argv[1:]
fileName = args[0]

if args.__contains__("-h"):
    print("""-----Help-----
This command will compile your code to a binary file, then create a floppy disk image from it, then run the floppy disk image in qemu.

-----args-----
This section will contain all possible arguments, and their uses

-----
-l
    'leave': don't delete the files included in the process of compliling
    
-----
-h
    'help': shows a help message""")
    quit()

outName = fileName.split(".")[0]

commands = ["nasm " + fileName.split(" ")[0] + " -f bin -o " + outName + ".bin",
            "dd status=noxfer conv=notrunc if=" + outName + ".bin of=" + outName + ".img",
            "unset GTK_PATH",
            "qemu-system-i386 -fda " + outName + ".img"]

for comm in commands:
    os.system(comm)
    
if not args.__contains__("-l"):    
    os.remove(outName + ".bin"); os.remove(outName + ".img")
```

Comment: You're comparing the address.  Also, EDX is a 32-bit register, so to load a 16-bit `dw 12` into it, you'd want `movzx edx, word [pos1]`.  Or just compare DX.